# ld: unexpected token: !tapi-tbd-v2 file Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode7, xcode8

I have develop an application using Xcode 7.3.1 but i have added Notification Service extension for iOS 10 by adding another target in Xcode 8. When i compile this app using Xcode 8 app compiles and runs but it ruin all AutoLayout constraints due to which i need to build this app from Xcode 7.
But when i compile this code from Xcode 7 it gives me this error.

> ld: unexpected token: !tapi-tbd-v2 file
>   '/Users/temp/Desktop/tipple/TippleDoc iOS 10
>   Notification/UserNotifications.framework/UserNotifications.tbd' for
>   architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have remove Notification Service Extension and UserNotification Framework as well. Tried enabling and disabling BIT_CODE but it still prompt this error.

Comment: I have got the same situation but in my case i explicitly copy `UserNotification.framework` from Xcode8 and then import it into my Xcode 7 Project. `cmd` + `shift` + `k` and then build.